# Concise recursive invocation of function with many parameters, changing only one parameter

Tags: r, recursion

I have an R function, `fun`, with many parameters. I need to run `fun` several times, varying the parameters `y` and `z` but keeping the others the same. Rather than wrap every call of `fun` in a loop, I made `y` and `z` both `NA` by default; the function checks if `is.na(y)` or `is.na(z)` and, if so, calls itself recursively with each desired value of `y` and `z` in turn, like this:

```
fun <- function(a=defaultA, b=defaultB, ..., y = NA, z=NA) {
  if (is.na(y)) {
    for (yValue in 1:maxY) {
      fun(a, b, ..., y = yvalue, z = z)
    }
    return()
  }
  if (is.na(z)) {
    for (zValue in 1:maxZ) {
      fun(a, b, ..., y, z=zValue)
    }
    return()
  }
  stopifnot(!is.na(y) && !is.na(z))
  # Part of fun that does actual work follows.
  ...
}
```

The recursive `fun` calls are actually inconveniently long, a few hundred characters each, because they need to repeat every parameter given to `fun`. Is there any shortcut by which I can call `fun` recursively with all parameters but one preserved, or is there another, better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

For the curious: my actual `fun` produces a graph with data sets and options specified in the parameters, and `y` and `z` are Booleans that determine whether to graph specific outliers. This lets me produce with- and without-outliers versions of the graphs without duplicating the function calls or wrapping them in for-loops as `for (y in c(TRUE, FALSE)) {for (z in c(TRUE, FALSE)) {fun(...)}}`.

Comment: How about putting all the parameters in a vector/data.frame/list and passing that as a single argument to `fun`?

Comment: That's a good thought! But the arguments aren't of the same type (so no vectors), and I rely heavily on the default arguments; I suppose I could make a list of the arguments and modify it as needed for each call, but I'd have to be careful to un-modify it afterward (otherwise I'll have non-default arguments from one call sticking around for the next).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match.call` and `sys.call` are your friends here. See [Why is match call useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486753/why-is-match-call-useful)

In your case, here's a rewritten version of the first loop:

```
fun <- function(a = defaultA, b = defaultB, ..., y = NA, z = NA) {
  if (is.na(y)) {
    mc <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    for (yvalue in 1:maxY) {
      mc[['y']] <- yvalue
      eval(mc)
    }
  }
  ...
```